# How can one get the value from SystemInformation::KeyboardSpeed (Windows API) in c code?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED, 0, &dwSpeed, 0);

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you call SystemParametersInfo with corresponding flag (SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED) instead?